# Spring REST DELETE example error

Tags: spring, rest, http, curl, http-delete

I want to implement Spring REST methods. I tried Get and it works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{systemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Configuration getConfigurationInJSON(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable long systemId) throws IOException {
        if (configurationMap.containsKey(systemId)) {
            return configurationMap.get(systemId);
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However when I want to implement DELETE it doesn't. My method is that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{systemId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteConfiguration(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable long systemId) throws IOException {
        if (configurationMap.containsKey(systemId)) {
            configurationMap.remove(systemId);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
```

My web.xml as follows:

mvc-dispatcher
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        1

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Command that works when I try with Curl for GET:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ui/webapp/conf/1
```

Command that doesn't work when I try with Curl for DELETE:

```
curl -x delete http://localhost:8080/ui/webapp/conf/1
```

Second command gives that error after a time later at curl:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

There is no error at Tomcat side and at debug it doesn't enter the delete method body.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/ui/webapp/conf/1
```

with uppercase `DELETE` and uppercase `X`

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg: you are right, I have corrected/extended the answer